# Rows as Columns Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to display the rows of a table as columns, this is the normal output:

```
  ITEM | CODE |    SET   | CREATION | CATEGORY  | GROUP
    1      1       CP     06/11/2020     10        52
    2      3       PN     07/11/2020      9        57
    3      1       PNI    08/11/2020     12        53
```

This is how I need to display it:

```
  ITEM         |      1     |     2      |    3    
  CODE         |      1     |     3      |    1
  SET          |      CP    |     PN     |    PNI
  CREATION     | 06/11/2020 | 07/11/2020 | 08/11/2020
  CATEGORY     |      10    |     9      |    12
  GROUP        |      52    |     57     |    53
```

I'm quite new to SQL, I tried to use the Oracle pivot function but I'm not getting the desired output, Is this even posible? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the number of "items" known in advance? If not, you will need dynamic SQL - this is an advanced topic, and not a good practice to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably `union all`.  Assuming all columns are strings:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by item) as seqnum
      from yourtable
     )
select 'item',
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then item end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then item end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then item end)
from t
union all
select 'code',
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then code end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then code end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then code end)
from t
union all
select 'set',
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then set end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then set end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then set end)
from t
union all
-- and so on for the rest of the columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Transposing means unpivot, then pivot (along different dimensions).

When you unpivot, you put together values of different data types in the same column of the (intermediate) result set. That can't work; you must first convert everything to strings. (Which means that, if you have data that cannot be converted to strings, the whole project will fail.) Note that, for simplicity, I set my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to `'dd/mm/yyyy'`; in production code, you should give explicit format model in the `TO_CHAR` call for dates.

Also, you need to know the number of input rows (items) in advance - otherwise you must use dynamic SQL, which is not an intro level topic - and not a good practice anyway.

Here is how it goes. Note that I changed two column names (`SET` and `GROUP` are reserved keywords in Oracle, they can't be column names) in the sample data, which I included in the `WITH` clause. Of course, the `WITH` clause is not part of the solution - it's there just for testing.

I also used an advanced feature of `UNPIVOT`, to create a column to order by at the end. That is not critical - you can use a more elementary version of `UNPIVOT`, and use a different approach to get the output in the right order.

```
with
  sample_data (ITEM, CODE, set_, creation, category, group_) as (
    select 1, 1, 'CP' , to_date('06/11/2020'), 10, 52 from dual union all
    select 2, 3, 'PN' , to_date('07/11/2020'),  9, 57 from dual union all
    select 3, 1, 'PNI', to_date('08/11/2020'), 12, 53 from dual
  )
select  col, "1", "2", "3"
from    ( 
          select to_char(item) as item, to_char(code) as code, set_, 
                 to_char(creation) as creation, to_char(category) as category,
                 to_char(group_) as group_, rownum as rn
          from   sample_data
        )
unpivot (value for (col, ord) in (item as ('ITEM', 1), code as ('CODE', 2),
               set_ as ('SET', 3), creation as ('CREATION', 4),
               category as ('CATEGORY', 5), group_ as ('GROUP', 6)))
pivot   (min(value) for rn in (1, 2, 3))
order    by ord
;

COL      1                    2                    3
-------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
ITEM     1                    2                    3
CODE     1                    3                    1
SET      CP                   PN                   PNI
CREATION 06/11/2020           07/11/2020           08/11/2020
CATEGORY 10                   9                    12
GROUP    52                   57                   53
```